# Why ROP attacks occur despite buffer overflow detection?

Tags: security, llvm, buffer-overflow

I read these sentences in wikipedia about ROP:
"Return-oriented programming is an advanced version of a stack smashing attack. Generally, these types of attacks arise when an adversary manipulates the call stack by taking advantage of a bug in the program, often a buffer overrun."

That means if buffer overrun don't occur, ROP will not occur. But some compilers (in my case LLVM) supports detection of buffer overflow, but defense against ROP is open in them.

I'm confused. Is there something that I didn't consider?

Comment: ROP is an exploitation technique when you can control data on the stack (i. e., the return address of a function call, generally through an overflow of a buffer on the stack) but the stack isn’t executable.

Comment: Also, what could be called a "buffer overflow" can often occur as part of a method of further exploiting another bug class. For example, a type confusion that leads to read/write beyond the bounds of an array with precision (i.e. access one specific piece of memory out of bounds, not smash an entire area. This is difficult to detect because a static analyzer cannot take into consideration that internal structures of the object might be manipulated directly by some other confused object. If this assumption was made, a static analysis engine would flag everything as dangerous.

Comment: The answer of your question is in the Section 2.1 of the paper https://www.usenix.org/system/files/conference/usenixsecurity14/sec14-paper-goktas.pdf

Answer (score 4):

According to [this Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buffer_overflow_protection)

> Clang supports three buffer overflow detectors, namely
>   AddressSanitizer (-fsanitize=address), -fsanitize=bounds, and
>   SafeCode. These systems have different tradeoffs in terms of
>   performance penalty, memory overhead, ***and classes of detected bugs***.

So it can only detect certain classes of bugs (not all of them), which means that it has false negatives.

The problem mainly lies with the fact that any static analysis of programs cannot, ***in general***, be both sound and complete. That is, any static analysis trying to detect buffer overflow will either have false positives and/or false negatives. This is a corollary of [Rice's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rice%27s_theorem), which intuitively states that any nontrivial property of programs is ***generally*** undecidable. The word "***generally***" here is important and means for ***all*** programs.

A **false positive** is when a static analysis flags a program statement as a buffer overflow while it is not.
A **false negative** is when a static analysis flags a program statement as a safe buffer access while it is not.

The most widely adopted approach in many fields not just buffer overflow detection (e.g., signature-based intrusion detection) is to tolerate false negatives rather false positives because false positives will otherwise be too many and will inundate programmers and obscure the real problems. That approach is also applied if the detection problem is decidable but too complex (e.g., NP-hard) to solve exactly. Bottom line, ***approximations permeate computer science***.

Comment: -fsanitize=address, -fsanitize=bounds, and SafeCode are not static analysis techniques. Much fewer buffer overflow bugs are detected by Clang as a static analyzer (emitting warnings at compile-time) than are detected by these techniques. As such this answer does not answer the title of the question “Why ROP attacks occur despite buffer overflow detection?“

Comment: Actually the question was never a question about static analysis (you added the tag in a question where it did not belong) and this entire answer is irrelevant to the original question.

Comment: @PascalCuoq Have you got any idea about my question? I haven't found my answer yet.

Answer (score 3):

Several techniques can be used to detect the possibility of a buffer overflow **at run-time**.

One, very cheap and enabled by default in code generated by modern compilers, only detects buffer overflows on the stack, only probabilistically (the buffer overflow has, say, (2<sup>32</sup>-1)/2<sup>32</sup> chances of being detected), and only checks for them just before returning from protected functions (which is a very good time to check but means the detection is not instantaneous). It works by inserting a “canary” value that the attacker wouldn't be able to predict at the top of the stack frame when the function begins its execution, and by checking the value of the canary at the end of the function 's execution.

The above technique is very interesting because it is cheap; in one single check, it protects well against all stack-based buffer overflows that could have happened during the function. However:

- It does not protect against heap-based buffer overflows.
- The attacker can limit themselves to a small stack-based buffer overflow in order to change the contents of some local variables and function arguments, without overwriting the canary. This may be enough to gain control of the target.
- The attacker can try their luck at guessing the value of the canary. With one chance in 2<sup>32</sup> at each try, if they are allowed to cause as many buffer overflows as they want (say, in a server that is not monitored and is automatically restarted after each crash), they may eventually get lucky.
- According to [this article](http://www.outflux.net/blog/archives/2014/01/27/fstack-protector-strong/), GCC developers felt that even protecting every function with a single check was still too much (the option I have been describing is called `-fstack-protector` in GCC), and they used heuristics to omit the check from various functions, including some where it could have been useful.

At the other end of the spectrum, there exist techniques that detect all possibilities of buffer overflow at run-time, at a greater cost.

**There is nothing impossible about systematically preventing all buffer overflows at run-time.** It is only more expensive than the above cheap check. Some techniques, while more efficient, are cheap enough to belong in compiler features, so you many find them as disabled-by-default options in Clang or GCC. The techniques that detect all buffer overflows, on heap as well as on stack, incur an overhead that can go up to, say, 900% (they make execution 10 times slower). Most people in charge of deploying software do not find this compromise acceptable, and thus these techniques are found only in [specialized academic C compilers](http://www.seclab.cs.sunysb.edu/mscc/), in [source-to-source transformation tools sold separately from the compiler](http://www.semdesigns.com/Products/MemorySafety/), or in [sound static analyzers used as C interpreters](http://blog.frama-c.com/public/csmith.pdf).

To reiterate, there is nothing impossible about detecting all buffer overflows at run-time. Rice's theorem does not apply. The instrumentation techniques to do so are only too expensive (in run-time speed) to be used in practice.

---

Another possibility, which is differently expensive, is to statically check that the program does not have any possibility of buffer overflow, for any possible input that might be sent to it. This way, the program can be compiled with an ordinary compiler and run at full speed without risk of remote code execution. This is where Rice's theorem begin to apply: it says that it is impossible to make an automatic static analyzer that guarantees that all safe programs are safe. This is no issue in practice, because Rice's theorem does not say that it is impossible to guarantee that one particular safe program is safe.
The important thing is to build a static analyzer that never says “safe” for a program that it cannot guarantee to be safe. The static analyzer is always allowed to say “maybe”, and the only difficulty in practice is if it says “maybe” too often, because it is never sure that any program is safe.

The above kind of static analyzer is called a *sound* static analyzer. They are a little difficult to use and are mostly discussed in academia only, but for instance, I work at [a company](http://trust-in-soft.com) that sells a sound static analyzer and the expertise to apply it to security-critical C software components. The first C library we verified is [PolarSSL](https://polarssl.org), used in a specific configuration. Because we have checked that no buffer overflow can occur for any message sent from the network to a PolarSSL server in the configuration we chose, it can be compiled with an ordinary compiler and is safe from all consequences of buffer overflows (and generally of C's undefined behaviors), including ROP attacks.